Вопрос был куда переводить деньги.Ответ :Сбер, Тинькофф за налог спишет.Рпсто
Запятая перечисляет банки?Или надо было переводить на сбер потому что с Тинькова спишут деньги.Вопрос куда переводить.Ответ :Сбер, Тинькофф за налог спишет

Переводить на Сбер, так как Тинькофф спишет деньги из-за налога. Запятая не перечисляет, а разделяет.
